# Discrepancy of GDP and International Transaction Releases for Exports

Tags: gdp, international-trade, international-economics

The Bureau of Economic Analysis ("BEA") provides consolidated data from several different government agencies. Currently they provide exports under both a Gross Domestic Product ("GDP") release as well as a International Transaction release. My questions are: 1) What is the difference between these two measures and 2) What are the corresponding export series in FRED for both releases?

Here are the links to the BEA data sources:

1) GDP Release: https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=19&step=2#reqid=19&step=2&isuri=1&1921=survey

2) International Transaction Release:
https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?ReqID=62&step=1

I should add that I have been attempting to retrieve the data from FRED for goods and services separately (both releases). Here is a link of where I am so far:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=nPkt